# Special case of mirror formula

Tags: optics

Can anyone show me how to prove the mirror formula when the object is between focus and pole in a concave mirror

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackexchange. Could you please clarify what mirror formula you are referring to, what is the difficulty you find in proving it, or why it is harder in the case you state?

Comment: 1/v +1/u = 1f , i observed in the other cases, when the concave mirror is forming real images , it was quite easy to prove through similarities , but when it formed virtual image , I was unable to prove it .